How to prep for Dryer vent cleaning service with washtower?
I live in a condo with a tight laundry room space that has a washtower over a drain pan. My question is how much room does Stanley Steemers need to get to the dryer vent to clean? Also, what is the easiest way to move my washtower? It’s just me and it’s on a drain pan.
If it wasn’t for the drain pan, I think I would just use an airlift. So I’m not sure how I should do this now with the drain plan sitting under it.

Forgot to mention, it’s in a tight laundry room closet space

Pictures would help.

I live in a condo and the yearly dryer vent cleaning is done through the vent termination port on the roof.

What you do is ask the contractor what they need you to do.
If it was not you who contracted this service you ask the person responsible and follow their guidance.
